# How to make a value in php update every second

Tags: php, html, ajax, web, reload

I want the "Visitors online: 001" on my stats.php site to update the visitors 5 secounds. it works if i reload the page and have another device with a different ip with the page open. I would really appreciate some help with this. it could be a small code i could include that i can change to update the counter or anything will help me.

[Here`s a image showing the counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clV2X.png)

```
<?php
/*************************************************************************
php easy :: online visitors counter scripts set - PHP Include Version
==========================================================================
Author: php easy code, www.phpeasycode.com
Web Site: http://www.phpeasycode.com
Contact: webmaster @ phpeasycode.com
*************************************************************************/
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "12345678";
$dbname = "db";
// Connection to database
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo 'NOT_OK';
    //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

$dbfile = "visitors.db"; // path to data file
$expire = 300; // average time in seconds to consider someone online before removing from the list

if(!file_exists($dbfile)) {
die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!");
}

if(!is_writable($dbfile)) {
die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!");
}

function CountVisitors() {
global $dbfile, $expire;
$cur_ip = getIP();
$cur_time = time();
$dbary_new = array();

$dbary = unserialize(file_get_contents($dbfile));
if(is_array($dbary)) {
while(list($user_ip, $user_time) = each($dbary)) {
if(($user_ip != $cur_ip) && (($user_time + $expire) > $cur_time)) {
$dbary_new[$user_ip] = $user_time;
}
}
}
$dbary_new[$cur_ip] = $cur_time; // add record for current user

$fp = fopen($dbfile, "w");
fputs($fp, serialize($dbary_new));
fclose($fp);

$out = sprintf("%03d", count($dbary_new)); // format the result to display 3 digits with leading 0's
return $out;
}

function getIP() {
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
else $ip = "0";
return $ip;
}

$visitors_online = CountVisitors();
?>
<p>Visitors online: <b><?=$visitors_online;?></b></p>
?>
```

Comment: You need to use clientside code for that, for example JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, a basic implementation could be done with AJAX.

Comment: @Qirel could you please show some examples im new to this.

Comment: Query the server by using AJAX, then replace the results into the div with the new result. Give it a go, if you get stuck - ask a new question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say..

You could do this with Javascript/Ajax, The reason for this is that the PHP is run on when the page loads so it will only show the value found when the page loads so having the database call in a separate file you can call with AJAX is the way to go.

Example pseudo code.

**PHP file**
getCustomerCount.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "12345678";
$dbname = "db";


if(isset($_POST['getCustomerCount']))
{
    // Connection to database
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {

        echo json_encode(['success'=> false,'error_message'=>"NOT_OK"]);
        //echo 'NOT_OK';
        //echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
    }

    $dbfile = "visitors.db"; // path to data file
    $expire = 300; // average time in seconds to consider someone online before removing from the list

    if(!file_exists($dbfile)) {
        echo json_encode(['success'=> false,'error_message'=>"Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!"]);
        die();
        //die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " NOT FOUND!");
    }

    if(!is_writable($dbfile)) {
        echo json_encode(['success'=> false,'error_message'=>"Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!"]);
        die();
        //die("Error: Data file " . $dbfile . " is NOT writable! Please CHMOD it to 666!");
    }

    $count = CountVisitors($dbfile, $expire);
    if(is_numeric($count)){
        $out = sprintf("%03d", $count); // format the result to display 3 digits with leading 0's
        echo json_encode(['success'=>'true', 'customer_count'=>$out]);
    }
    else 
    {
        echo json_encode(['success'=> false, 'error_message'=>"count is not numeric"]);
    }
}
else{
    echo json_encode($_POST);
}


function CountVisitors() {
    global $dbfile, $expire;
    $cur_ip = getIP();
    $cur_time = time();
    $dbary_new = array();

    $dbary = unserialize(file_get_contents($dbfile));
    if(is_array($dbary)) {
        while(list($user_ip, $user_time) = each($dbary)) {
            if(($user_ip != $cur_ip) && (($user_time + $expire) > $cur_time)) {
                $dbary_new[$user_ip] = $user_time;
            }
        }
    }
    $dbary_new[$cur_ip] = $cur_time; // add record for current user

    $fp = fopen($dbfile, "w");
    fputs($fp, serialize($dbary_new));
    fclose($fp);

    return count($dbary_new);
}

function getIP() {
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    elseif(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = "0";
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

**Javascript file**.
getCustomerCount.js

```
$(function(){
    //Set interval function to update after set time
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        updateCustomerCount();
    }, 5000);
});

function updateCustomerCount()
{
    $.ajax({
        url:"getCustomerCount.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{getCustomerCount:true},
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
            var data = $.parseJSON(response);
            if(data.success)
            {
                $("#customer_count span").text(data.customer_count);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(data.error_message);
            }

        },
        error:function(response){
            console.log("Server Error");
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML file**.
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="customer_count">Customers Online: <span></span></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="getCustomerCount.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

That should work for you as an example on how to do it but I advise cleaning it up and looking into the different parts to see how they can be improved upon for your usage.